# Passing a "reference" to Dictionary element?

Tags: c#

So I have:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dict;
```

I want to pass a reference to one of its elements, suppose `dict["x"]` to a method, and allow that method to change/set that element. Is it possible to do exactly that, or do I have to pass the dictionary itself? Also, is it possible to do so even if the element does not exist as a key in the dictionary? Or does it already has to be a valid key contained in the dictionary?

Comment: You can try it and see if it is possible or not.

Comment: I tried, it only passes the value if I do dict["x"], and the changes are not reflected back to the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using a delegate. This delegate can be called from within the changing function. The delegate will then change or set the key/value inside the dictionary.

```
void DoChangeMyElement<T>(Action<T> changeIt)
{
    changeIt(123);
}
```

You can call this method with:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> dict = new ...;
DoChangeMyElement(value => dict["X"] = value);
```

Comment: very strange approach to do that. You advice to use delegates, closure, lambda to achieve really simple behavior.

Comment: @Artur: Absolutely! But it does exactly what he is asking for. I admit that the thing what Hossein wants is not my preference of doing things, but hey, who am I to argue? :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up using this, and apparently its the only way to do it without having to pass the dictionary. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in passing the whole `Dictionary`.  It itself is a reference type after all, and passing the `Dictionary` would be better form than passing by reference.

but I suppose you could encapsulate you int and pass it like that

```
public class IntContainer
{
    int value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think thats the safest approach to take. The problem is that that method is in a thread thats controlled by another remote computer, so passing the dictionary as a whole adds a risk of another party reading or even altering all of its keys, while it should be able to edit only specific key value.

Comment: @xander if you're doing networking like that, than that's a whole other animal.  Passing by reference over a network doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Using the `ref` keyword won't help here.  The result of the dictionary's indexer is not a variable, and thus you can't pass it by reference.  The only option is to pass the whole dictionary, or create a new object that holds a reference to the dictionary and the key and pass that.

Comment: it's times like this where i wish that i still had the edits before the grace period

Comment: @Sam I am Thank you so much for your suggestion. I ended up creating a delegate which the thread would call it to change the particular value. Its not the "optimal" approach I think, but it worked fine thankfully. Your approach could have worked just as fine I think, only would have had to have a new object holding reference to the particular value to change, because like Servy said can't pass dictionary indexer. I am not sending the reference over the network, its to an internal thread thats responsible for handling connections with a particular peer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass a reference to one of its elements, suppose dict["x"] to a method, and allow that method to change/set that element. Is it possible to do exactly that, or I have to pass the dictionary itself ?

Just pass the dictionary, as Sam I am said it is a reference type anyway.

> Also, is it possible to do so even if the element does not exist as a key in the dictionary ?

No that's not possible, you'd have to add to it, then send it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to pass the whole dictionary and key, and let the method do what it needs to. The basic reason for this is that you can only pass fields and local variables by reference, not properties (including indexer properties).

If you were really desperate to do so, you could use reflection and/or delegates to get what you want done, but it's not the best way to do it.